# As bordas da tabela desaparecem na impressão

Tags: javascript, css

Boa noite a todos. Galera estou tentando imprimir uma 'div' que contém uma tabela com bordas. Porém, a tabela perde a borda na tela de impressão. tentei usar '@media print', porém sem sucesso. Criei uma função para imprimir a div, ela é chamada através do botão imprimir.

```js
function cont(div){
   var conteudo = document.getElementById(div).innerHTML;
   tela_impressao = window.open('about:blank');
   tela_impressao.document.write(conteudo);
   tela_impressao.window.print();
   tela_impressao.window.close();
}
```

```css
table{
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table td{

            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        @media print{
            table td{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        }
        .pp{
            width: 30px;
        }
```

```html
<head>
    <title>Imprimir</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="cont('print');" value="Imprimir">
    <div id="print">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>nome</th>
                <th>email</th>
                <th>telefone</th>
                <th>P</th>
                <th>F</th>
                <th>FJ</th>
            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>Allan da costa</td>
                <td>allancomprax@hotmail.com</td>
                <td>(21)97339-1150</td>
                <td class="pp"></td>
                <td class="pp"></td>
                <td class="pp"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, isso acontece porque a função só vai fazer print dos valores para impressão, e não das bordas porque faz parte do código .css . O melhor será procurar por um conversor para gerar um pdf que lei o .css

Comment: Valeu Miguel pela resposta, mas você teria uma ideia de como fazer isso, não sei nem por onde começar.